# 14 days of suspension

Tags: discussion, support, account-suspension

I have been suspended for 14 days. I wrote a rude comment I admit (but I was provoked).

Do I have any way to try to get a lower supension? With this supension I will not be able to assign a bounty I opened some days ago in one of my questions.

Please note I didn't receive any warning. I just received this 14 days suspension after I wrote that stupid comment.

Comment: If your history on Meta is anything to go by, I think you should use those 14 days to reflect on your participation on the site.

Comment: if a comment is worth a ban then in most cases the poster is not going to care if they are notified or not. Have you a link to the question or comment (if they have not been deleted).

Comment: the question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091446/bind-dreamweaver-for-a-particular-code-hint but all comments were deleted

Comment: if moderators shows any interest on you, you will be getting private messsage , asking for explanation of ur suspention.

Comment: @Ivo what problematic Meta behaviour are you referring to exactly? I'm having a hard time seeing anything out of the ordinary

Comment: @yes123, @Pekka, possibly the tone and grammar?

Comment: @tombull he's not a native english speaker so let's be easy on the grammar (which ain't that bad IMO btw). Re tone, can you show an example?

Comment: @tombull: did you mean gramm*a*r? :) (aww you edited your error now :P)

Comment: A single spelling mistake is a moot point. `YES, I AM a human being! Doh! add1: LOL guys, why you are making fun of this?`. I mean, really?

Comment: @Pekka 5/10 of his questions are deleted and 2 out of the 5 remaining questions are closed. And judging by his questions on SO, he's not doing great there either.

Comment: @Ivo on stackoverflow out of 170 questions I have got less than 10 closed questions. And I received +121 vote up with a total of ~2000 reputation (before the suspension). Sorry but I don't think I was going so bad at S.O. And If you read all my accepted answer and comments I tried to be always grammar-errors-free and nice.

Comment: @tombull but that is hardly an example of bad tone, is it? In the context of the question?

Comment: Make sure you have a valid email address associated with your SO account.  According to the penalty box posting, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/, they will try to contact you before suspending your account if they think they can.  I would say that if you had a valid email address, got no warning, and this really was your first negative interaction where a mod got involved, you should have a strong case to have it reduced or eliminated, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I a valid email And yes this is my first negative interaction with a mod. My email is clearly wrote in my profile yet I didn't received any warns. I only received in email the message that explained my suspesion.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Warnings are sometimes given for first offenses, but not if the violation is egregious. From the penalty box blog post: *"The odds of moderators contacting you with a warning first will be in direct proportion to how much evidence you’ve given us that you are, in fact, a potentially valuable and contributing member of the community."*

Comment: Just to clarify, there was indeed a message sent at the start of the suspension, just not a prior warning. It is in fact impossible to suspend a user without simultaneously sending a message.

Comment: The message was something like: `"There's a relevant section from the FAQ that reads: <Be Nice. Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. [...]. Bring your sense of humor.>

This is a cooldown suspension of 14 days. Looking through your history I can see that you obviously have a lot of knowledge to share, we just need you to find a more constructive way to share it"`

Comment: care to explain downvotes?

Comment: My guess is that people disagree that your suspension time period should be reduced. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: @Cody: witout even reading the comment that caused the suspension? Hmm ok.

Comment: Presumably, they remain unconvinced that we need to make a special-case exception for you. They trust our moderators to make the right decision and not drop the suspension hammer unless it's absolutely necessary. I, for example, fall into that camp...

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to reduce a sentence. It doesn't happen often, but it is possible.

You need a strong enough case to prove that you should have a smaller sentence. When you got suspended, you should've gotten a notice that explained it (which is what I assume told you that it was for your behavior in comments). Use that as a channel of communication to negotiate for an early release, just make sure you can prove that you don't need the full 14 days.

Note that the simple presence of a live bounty, I wouldn't expect that alone to suffice as a strong case. You're far from the first instance of a suspended user who has a live bounty.

Comment: Thanks for answer and.. Well I don't want to steal time from mods, if a mod will read this question and will find my points valid I hope I can get a lower penalty.